# Boundary conditions OF PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I am reading an article and I want to solve its PDE , but in this article, its boundary conditions are not specified. The author has said about it as follows:

"Boundary conditions are given by the numerical solution of the PDE for the deterministic case"

Can anyone help me what it means above?

Comment: Can't say anything without context. Do you have a link to this article?

Comment: https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03461238.2015.1020856

Comment: PDE is on page 23 of the above article .